# Create .wav file using C#

Tags: c#

I have nessary chunk header bytes for a wave file stored in a text file. What I'd like to do is create a new .wav that will vary in data length and write into it 50ms/10kHz signals(which is stored in separate file). How can I accomplish with .NET/C#?

-Mickey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the System.IO.BinaryReader and System.IO.BinaryWriter streams to read data from your signals files, write binary datatypes to a file, as per the wav file specification.